# Conversion from categorical to numerical variable leads to NA error

Tags: r

so this is my problem. I am trying to convert categorical variables into numerical, but when I try to do this the "NA introduced by coercion" error appears. How can I solve this?

My dataset:

```
str(Movies)
```

```
'data.frame':   51945 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ id                  : int  150540 14160 12 354912 10681 585 862 8587 9806 808 ...
 $ title               : chr  "Inside Out" "Up" "Finding Nemo" "Coco" ...
 $ vote_average        : num  7.92 7.95 7.82 8.22 8.08 ...
 $ vote_count          : int  19463 18857 18061 17742 17446 17189 17152 16991 16584 15765 ...
 $ status              : chr  "Released" "Released" "Released" "Released" ...
 $ release_date        : chr  "2015-06-09" "2009-05-28" "2003-05-30" "2017-10-27" ...
 $ revenue             : int  857611174 735099082 940335536 800526015 521311860 579707738 394400000 763455561 631442092 487853320 ...
 $ runtime             : int  95 96 100 105 98 92 81 89 115 90 ...
 $ adult               : chr  "False" "False" "False" "False" ...
 $ backdrop_path       : chr  "/j29ekbcLpBvxnGk6LjdTc2EI5SA.jpg" "/hGGC9gKo7CFE3fW07RA587e5kol.jpg" "/h3uqFk7sZRJvLZDdLiFB9qwbL07.jpg" "/askg3SMvhqEl4OL52YuvdtY40Yb.jpg" ...
 $ budget              : int  175000000 175000000 94000000 175000000 180000000 115000000 30000000 45000000 92000000 60000000 ...
 $ homepage            : chr  "http://movies.disney.com/inside-out" "http://disney.go.com/disneypictures/up/" "http://movies.disney.com/finding-nemo" "https://www.pixar.com/feature-films/coco" ...
 $ imdb_id             : chr  "tt2096673" "tt1049413" "tt0266543" "tt2380307" ...
 $ original_language   : chr  "en" "en" "en" "en" ...
 $ original_title      : chr  "Inside Out" "Up" "Finding Nemo" "Coco" ...
 $ overview            : chr  "Growing up can be a bumpy road, and it's no exception for Riley, who is uprooted from her Midwest life when her"| __truncated__ "Carl Fredricksen spent his entire life dreaming of exploring the globe and experiencing life to its fullest. Bu"| __truncated__ "Nemo, an adventurous young clownfish, is unexpectedly taken from his Great Barrier Reef home to a dentist's off"| __truncated__ "Despite his family’s baffling generations-old ban on music, Miguel dreams of becoming an accomplished musician "| __truncated__ ...
 $ popularity          : num  107.3 91 55.5 166.6 58.5 ...
 $ poster_path         : chr  "/2H1TmgdfNtsKlU9jKdeNyYL5y8T.jpg" "/vpbaStTMt8qqXaEgnOR2EE4DNJk.jpg" "/ggQ6o8X5984OCh3kZi2UIJQJY5y.jpg" "/gGEsBPAijhVUFoiNpgZXqRVWJt2.jpg" ...
 $ tagline             : chr  "Meet the little voices inside your head." "The greatest adventure is just getting back home." "There are 3.7 trillion fish in the ocean. They're looking for one." "The celebration of a lifetime" ...
 $ genres              : chr  "Animation, Family, Adventure, Drama, Comedy" "Animation, Comedy, Family, Adventure" "Animation, Family" "Family, Animation, Fantasy, Music, Comedy, Adventure" ...
 $ production_companies: chr  "Pixar, Walt Disney Pictures" "Pixar" "Pixar" "Pixar, Walt Disney Pictures" ...
 $ production_countries: chr  "United States of America" "United States of America" "United States of America" "United States of America" ...
 $ spoken_languages    : chr  "English" "English" "English" "English, Spanish" ...
> dim(Movies)
```

I want to convert original_companies into a numerical variable. But when I do this:

```
Movies$production_companies <-as.numeric(Movies$production_companies)
```

This appears:

> Warning:
> NA introduced by coercion

```
str(Movies$production_companies)

num [1:51945] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Thank You!

Comment: For the vector `c("Pixar, Walt Disney Pictures", "Pixar", "Pixar", "Pixar, Walt Disney Pictures")` what output are you expecting? `c(1, 2, 2, 1)`? It's not clear from your post how you expect categorical responses to be mapped to numeric.

Comment: How about: `Movies$production_companies <-as.numeric(as.factor(Movies$production_companies))` ?

Comment: Thank You! @ZhiqiangWang. It works, but why I have to do this? I'm sorry I'm new to data science, trying to understand.

Comment: @Mia If you have a character value, like "Pixar", how would this be converted to a number? Which number? `as.numeric` tries to interpret an object as a number. I would read about [factors (section 3.4.1)](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html)...factors are build on integer vectors, which make them convenient for cases like these, when you have predefined categories...it will assign and store integers for each category in your vector. Depending on your use case, you can analyze/visualize data with factors nicely, and not need to have a specific numeric variable...

Comment: @Ben I am sorry, do I need to transform a variable from a categorical to a numerical one in order to scale data and divide data in training and testing, right? I mean, if I do not change the categorical variable into a numerical one, how can I actually proceed with Lasso, Ridge and OLS? If you have books suggestions or papers, that would be highly appreciated. As I said before, I am new to data science. Thank you.

Comment: @Mia Without knowledge of your experience to date, would definitely want to ensure you possess basic skills with R, including tidy data and basic transformation, such as [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/). As for analytic methods, you could consider [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/) with 2nd edition for R published a few years ago. I have 1st edition, and there's a chapter specifically on Linear Model Selection and Regularization, with step-by-step modeling using `glmnet` package.